# How to localize unity android game? (So that Google Play can see it)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play

I uploaded game in Google Play store and I didn't localize it. I can export the project from Unity to Android Studio and localize there. But it is extreme! What must I do? so that Google play can see that my game has been localized in lots of languages. Maybe `/res/values/string-en` || / `string-es` || etc. ?? How is it applied in code?

I have just two phrases, that I want translated and it's not gui gameobjects, they are initialize in the script.

P.S. Unity version 4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to localize things for Android under unity without exporting to Android studio, you should make the following as described in this [answer](https://answers.unity.com/answers/1311496/view.html)

> To add support for more locales, you must create additional
>   directories inside res/ each directory's name should adhere to the
>   following format:
>
> resource type-b+language code+country code
>
> For example, the folder values-b+es contains string resources for
>   locales with the language code es (Spanish), inside each folder will
>   go a strings.xml file with the texts on each language.
>
> You can add the new locales inside your Unity project creating the
>   following directory

```
Assets
 -> Plugins
    -> Android
       ->res
         ->values-b+en
           ->strings.xml  (with your text in english)
         ->values-b+es
           ->strings.xml  (with your text in spanish)
         ->values-b+fr
           ->strings.xml  (with your text in french)
         ...
         ...
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version(s) of Unity do not support localisation of strings.

You have to do this within your code or, as you say, export to AS and do the work there.

Comment: Thanks fo answer! My version Unity 4.7